# HP DL360 G7 - which power supply is "power supply 1"?

Tags: hp

Right now we are getting an intermittent error in iLO stating that "Power Supply 1" is failing. The issue is that there are two power supplies, and neither one is clearly labelled as "Power Supply 1." Since it is an intermittent issue, the error comes and goes (but appears resolved in between). We can't really look for an amber LED because right now the server doesn't detect a fault with the PSU. We want to pull the PSU and replace it with a spare we have on site. So, looking at the server from behind, is power supply 1 on the right or on the left?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the rear view, power supply #1 on a [**ProLiant DL360 G7**](http://h18004.www1.hp.com/products/quickspecs/13598_na/13598_na.html) is the right-most power supply bay.

[image]

Comment: @Matthew: Did it not occur to you to look in the documentation too ?

Comment: It did, but I'm currently on a conference call with limited access. Further, HP's documentation showing a particular bay name does not always match up with what iLO considers to be a particular port (for instance in G6's or G5's - i can't remember which, the listing of ethernet port names was reversed). Since I am directing others, I wanted to be certain.

Answer (score 5):

From the [quickspecs](http://h18000.www1.hp.com/products/quickspecs/13598_div/13598_div.PDF) documentation

[image: quickspecs]

Answer (score 2):

According to the diagram [here](http://h18004.www1.hp.com/products/quickspecs/13598_na/13598_na.html), Power Supply Bay 1 is the one on the right, closest to the edge of the server.